# Access vite Frontend through domain from /etc/hosts

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vite

On node v16 I could easily do

```
#/etc/hosts
127.0.0.1        localhost
255.255.255.255  broadcasthost
::1             localhost

127.0.0.1 my-domain.test
```

then access site through `my-domain.test:{port}`

On **node 18 this doesn't work** anymore, using the same vite config

```
// vite.config.ts
{
  server: {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3003
  },
  plugins: [vue(), vueJsx()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    }
  }
}
```

anybody has an Idea what changed?

Answer (score 1):

Just replace host in server section in vite.config.ts

```
 // vite.config.ts
{
  server: {
    host: 'my-domain.test',
    port: 3003
  }, ...
}
```